# Prove that if $e=f+gi$ is a solution of the equation $az^2 + bz+c=0$ with $ a \in \mathbb R_0 $ and $ b,c \in \mathbb R $

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that if $e= f+gi$ is a solution of the equation $ae^2 + be +c = 0$ with $a \in \mathbb R_0$; $b,c \in \mathbb R$ then the conjugate $\overline e= f-gi$ is also a solution of the equation.

Is it sufficient to use the discriminant formulae to get to the solutions as follows:

$$ y= \frac {-b+ \sqrt {b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$$ 
$$ y= \frac {-b- \sqrt {b^2 -4ac}}{2a}$$
?

Comment: Hint. Just substitute $\bar e$ in the equation instead of $e$ and see if you get $0$.

Comment: A stronger result is: If $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$ is a root of $f\in\Bbb R[x]$, then $\bar z$ is also a root of $f$, i.e., complex non-real roots of a polynomial with real coefficients always come in conjugate pairs. To see this, consider what happens to the constant term (also the other coefficients) of $f\in\Bbb R[x]$ if $f$ has a root $a+ib$ but the conjugate $a-ib$ is not a root of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you  noted we know that the solutions of the equation are
$$
e=\frac{-b}{2a} \pm \frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \qquad (1)
$$
where $\frac{-b}{2a}$ is  areal number

so, if
$
e=f+ig$  we have: $\quad f=\frac{-b}{2a}$ and $\quad ig=\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ , but, from $(1)$ also  $f-ig$ is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You have to use the rules for conjugate:

$$ \overline{z+w} = \overline{z}+ \overline{w}$$
$$ \overline{zw} = \overline{z}\cdot  \overline{w}$$
$$ \overline{z} = z \iff z\in \mathbb{R}$$
and
$$ \overline{z}^n = \overline{z^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes for quadratic case you have two solution    $$\frac{-b}{2a} \pm \frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

and  if complex, they are conjugate because the imaginary unit appears in front of the radical sign with $\pm $ signs which make them conjugates.

In general we have the same result  that in case of real coefficients,  complex roots of polynomials appear in conjugates.